# stricmp doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

i'm having a problem using stricmp in a specific function, in other functions it works perfectly, except this one.
the problem is that even if it compares the same string (char*) it doesn't return 0.
what might be the problem?
(sorry for the mess, i'll try formatting it)
that's the code:

```
Employee* CityCouncil::FindEmp(list<Employee*> *lst, char* id)  
{  
 bool continue1 = true;  
 Employee* tmp= NULL;  
 char* tmpId = NULL, *tmpId2 = NULL;  
 list<Employee*>::iterator iter = lst->begin();  
 if ((id == NULL) || (lst->empty()==true))  
  return NULL;  
 while ((iter != lst->end()) && (continue1)){  
  tmp = (Employee*)(*iter);  
  tmpId = (*tmp).GetId();  
  if(tmpId != NULL)  
  {  
      if(stricmp(tmpId,id) == 0)  
       continue1 = false;  
  }  
  if (continue1 == true)  
  iter++;  
 }  
 if (iter == lst->end())
     return NULL;
 return (Employee*)(*iter);
}
```

Comment: Please use the preview when posting questions. Corrected the source code formatting for you this time.

Comment: Please tag the question with the language (C/C++?). Visual studio supports many languages, so you need to be more specific.

Comment: According to the MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235365(v=VS.100).aspx - `stricmp` is now deprecated. You should use `_stricmp` instead - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59z8dwe.aspx

Comment: stop editing the post, you are removing the code formatting each time. There needs to be **4** spaces before each line to get the code formatting working. You'll also trigger the conversion of the post to community wiki and you'll gain no reputation from any up-votes you might receive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never blame a function that belongs to the C library. stricmp surely works as expected, meaning the strings are really different. There must be something wrong with the logic in this function - you should use `printf` statements to find out where and why the strings differ.

**EDIT:** I put together a simple test program. This works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

// Dummy
class Employee
{
    public:
        Employee(const char *n){ id = strdup(n); }
        char *id;
        char *GetId() { return this->id; }
};

Employee* FindEmp(list<Employee*> *lst, char* id)
{
    bool continue1 = true;
    Employee *tmp = NULL;
    char* tmpId = NULL;

    list<Employee*>::iterator iter = lst->begin();
    if(id == NULL || lst->empty())
        return NULL;

    while(iter != lst->end() && continue1)
    {
        tmp = (Employee*)(*iter);
        tmpId = (*tmp).GetId();
        if(tmpId != NULL)
        {
            if(stricmp(tmpId,id) == 0)
                continue1 = false;
        }
        if(continue1 == true)
            iter++;
    }

    if(iter == lst->end())
        return NULL;

    return (Employee*)(*iter);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    list<Employee*> l;

    l.push_back(new Employee("Dave"));
    l.push_back(new Employee("Andy"));
    l.push_back(new Employee("Snoopie"));

    printf("%s found\n", FindEmp(&l, "dave")->GetId());
    printf("%s found\n", FindEmp(&l, "andy")->GetId());
    printf("%s found\n", FindEmp(&l, "SnoOpiE")->GetId());

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I used the function you provided. Again, there is nothing wrong with stricmp, the problem must be in your code.

Comment: just to make sure, a getter of char* field automatically adds a null terminator at the end of the string?

Comment: No... There are no getters/setters in C++. There are functions and methods that do exactly what you tell them to do (more exactly: what you code them to do). The `return` statement in GetId just returns the value of the pointer. If I'm right in assuming that your question is about an assignment, you should read up about how strings, pointers etc. work in C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct; maybe you're not passing in the strings that you think you are, or maybe memory is getting corrupted somehow?

However, your function could be written much more cleanly.

```
// Why is this a method off of CityCouncil?  As written, it
// doesn't use any CityCouncil members.
//
// Also, why not pass lst by reference?  Like this:
//    Employee* CityCoucil::FindEmp(list<Employee*>& lst, char *id) { ...
//
// Also, const correctness is a good idea, but that's more complicated.
// Start with this:
//    Employee* CityCoucil::FindEmp(const list<Employee*>& lst, const char *id) { ...
//
// Also, it's easy to leak memory when using a list of pointers, but that's
// another topic.
Employee* CityCouncil::FindEmp(list<Employee*> *lst, char* id)  
{
    // No need for continue1; we'll use an early return instead;
    // No need for tmp, tmpId, tmpId2; just call methods directly
    // off of iter.

    if (id == NULL || lst->empty())
        return NULL;

    // You should NOT do a C-style "(Employee*)" cast on *iter.
    // C-style casts are generally to be avoided, and in this case, 
    // it shouldn't be necessary.

    // Use a for loop to simplify your assigning iter and incrementing it.
    for (list<Employee*>::iterator iter = lst->begin(); iter != list->end(); iter++) {
        if ((*iter)->GetId()) {
            if (stricmp((*iter)->GetId(), id) == 0) {
                return *iter;
            }
        }
    }  
    return NULL;
}
```